# Python 3.6 keep log info in buffer and then send it

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, buffer, amazon-kinesis

I have a homemade tool that runs a lot of steps and then I'm caching all is going on with the package `import logging` and then writing it into a file for logging purposes.

I would like to make my process smarter and I was wondering how to keep all the data collected for the log steps in a buffer and then send it to cloud or a database table or any other destination.

thanks so much for your advice and approaches.

Comment: Might be good starting point: [QueueHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#queuehandler).

Comment: you can also try cloudwatch agents to push all your logs to cloudwatch monitoring to trigger other events.